# change picture in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

master1.master

HTML

```
<asp:Image ID="First" runat="server" />
```

---

tow.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/master1.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="two.aspx.cs" Inherits="ControlPanelPP"
Title="Untitled Page" %>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    how can change Image `First` in master1.master
}
```

how can change image in masterpage ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        Image First = new Image(); 
        First = (Image)(Page.Master.FindControl("First"));
        if (First != null)
        {
            First.ImageUrl = "image-path";
        }
```

Comment: CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

Answer (score 1):

Define a `property` in the code behind file of `master page`

```
public string ImagePath
{

get { return First.ImageUrl; }
set { First.ImageUrl = value; }

}
```

add @MasterType page directive in content page like this...

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/master1.master" %>
```

`tow.aspx` page load set that property...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

  ((master1)this.Master).ImagePath= "image_path";

}
```

Comment: I think I prefer this to the accepted answer.  Question though, do you need to cast this.Master to your master?

Answer (score -1):

```
((master)this.Master).image.Src = "~/images/titles/accesscontrol.jpg";
```

in one step